# How do you autocomplete from another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I followed the Railscast on [Auto-complete Associations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association) but i am stuck at the autocomplete half. I am not using Prototype but Jquery instead and i don't know how to get the autocomplete half working. How is it done?

This is the customization compared to what the Railscast has:

Products Model:

```
def location_name
    location.business_name if location
end

def location_name=(business_name)
    self.location = Location.find_by_business_name(business_name) unless business_name.blank?
end
```

The above makes a virtual attribute in which i defined my Location models `:business_name` into `location_name` for the `<%= f.text_field :location_name %>` of my products form because a product belongs to a Location.

**EDIT: This was using the [Jquery Autocomplete Gem](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) but i am open to alternatives.**

My product `:name` works a charm;

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_product_name_products_path %>
```

But if i put something like this for `:location_name` its no good;

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :location_name, autocomplete_product_location_name_products_path %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was simple, had to add `attr_accessor`, this is my finished code from another project:

```
<%= form_for(@business_address) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
    <%= f.label :name, "Address" %><br />
    <%= f.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_business_address_name_business_addresses_path %>
    <%= f.label :business_name, "Business" %>
    <%= f.autocomplete_field :business_name, autocomplete_business_name_business_addresses_path %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %


class BusinessAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :business_name
    belongs_to :business
    attr_accessor :business_name


    def business_name
        business.name if business
    end

    def business_name=(name)
        self.business = Business.find_or_create_by_name(name) unless name.blank?
    end
end

class BusinessAddressesController
  autocomplete :business, :name, :full => true
  autocomplete :business_address, :name, :full => true
end
```

Routes.rb

```
resources :business_addresses do
        get :autocomplete_business_name, :on => :collection
        get :autocomplete_business_address_name, :on => :collection
end
```

Make sure you specify in your application layout the files needed or for some strange reason it won't work (rails 3.0.9)

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "autocomplete-rails", "jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but have you tried using `autocomplete_location_location_name_products_path`?

Answer (score 0):

Since i couldn't get the Autocomplete working for the Jquery-Autocomplete i just started using [Jquery-TokenInput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) plugin for my locations and just set the Limit to 1 Token only, i learned a lot from the [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields) too.